# How can I put variable into session name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to put variable value to session name, like

```
session[:this_is_@profile_of] = "Smth"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so far?

Comment: @RobertRossmann I know, but the question is short. What can I do with it?

Comment: Ruby on Rails is one of the most popular web frameworks - there are tons of tutorials and code samples on the internets. You should try to find your answer first, use it, and if it does not work as you would expect, try to fix it. Only if it does not still work, ask on StackOverflow. That's how good questions are asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `to_sym` method:

```
session_key = "this_is_#{@profile}_of".to_sym

session[session_key] = "Smth"
```